# Catching timeout exception in for-loop

Tags: ruby, exception

For each file in directory, I need to do something to it, and then write the results to another file. If a timeout exception is raised, continue on to the next iteration of the loop.

```
 require 'timeout'
 timeout_in_seconds = 60

 for fl in Dir.glob('/dir/files')
     begin 
     Timeout::timeout(timeout_in_seconds) do 
 #do something here to get $results
 File.open('new_file', 'w') { |file| file.write(results) }
     end
     rescue Timeout::Error
 next
 end
```

Run from the shell the error is:

```
  syntax error, 'unexpected kRESCUE, expecting kEND
rescue Timeout::Error
```

Any ideas as to how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed two `end` in your code above. write it as below.

```
require 'timeout'
timeout_in_seconds = 60

 for fl in Dir.glob('/dir/files')
     begin 
     Timeout::timeout(timeout_in_seconds) do 
       #do something here to get $results
       File.open('new_file', 'w') { |file| file.write(results) }
     end
     rescue Timeout::Error
      next # although I am not sure why this is needed.
     end
 end
```

Comment: Uh, well, downvoting can be very useful viz. cutting out chafe/redundant posts.  Probably best to be diplomatic about all of this :-)

Comment: may be :) but people here also learning by answering,so whenever anything wrong,others should let him know,what's wrong. that can be a great teach... I think... :)

Answer (score 1):

The `rescue` should be before the end clause.

```
require 'timeout'
timeout_in_seconds = 60

for fl in Dir.glob('/dir/files')
  begin 
    Timeout::timeout(timeout_in_seconds) do 
    #do something here to get $results
    File.open('new_file', 'w') { |file| file.write(results) }
  rescue Timeout::Error

  end
end
```